# Why does mongoose connection hang when in separate module?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a relatively simple Node script that should open a mongodb connection (using mongoose), and return all records in a test collection.

For some reason, when I separate the `mongoose.connect` call into a separate module (because it's going to be used by multiple scripts) the script doesn't work. But when I make the `connect` call in the same file it does work.

**Broken Version**

*connect.js*

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var config = require("./_config");  // holds different mongo URIs for dev/prod

var mongoUrl = config.mongoURI[process.env.NODE_ENV];

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("connected", function () {
  console.log("Mongoose default connection open to " + mongoUrl);
});
```

*script.js*

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require("../server/connect");

var testSchema = new Schema({
  teststring: String
}, {
  timestamps: true
}, { bufferCommands: false });

var Tester = mongoose.model("Tester", testSchema);
Tester.find(function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
// node script.js
// Outputs "Mongoose default connection open to mongodb://localhost/test"
// then hangs
```

**Working version**

*script.js*

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var config = require("./_config");

var mongoUrl = config.mongoURI[process.env.NODE_ENV];

mongoose.connect(mongoUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("connected", function () {
  console.log("Mongoose default connection open to " + mongoUrl);
});

var testSchema = new Schema({
  teststring: String
}, {
  timestamps: true
}, { bufferCommands: false });

var Tester = mongoose.model("Tester", testSchema);
Tester.find(function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

This one-file version works fine and returns results. As you can see the only difference seems to be using 1 file vs. 2.

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - the `/server/` folder had its own `node_modules` folder, so `require("mongoose")` in `connect.js` was actually including a different instance of mongoose than the script. Reading [the node module docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) carefully helped me figure it all out.

Comment: I do not have any other `node_modules` folder in the project. I was trying to init a mongoose connection before all the `jest` tests were run. But the code used inside to libraries was hanging on `model.save()`. How did you manage to resolve the problem? When I tried to connect directly inside a test file, it was working

Comment: Thanks, it was the same for me!

Had a "core"-module (with mongoose schemas, models, etc) and a "backend"-module (should use the models defined in core). Both had "mongoose" installed and I couldn't use the core-models after making the connection from within backend.

After "npm remove mongoose" in the backend-module and initializing the connection from core it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting something from your './connect' module? Otherwise node won't have anything to keep and the connection will be garbage collected.

Add this as the last line:
`module.exports = db`

And then assign it to a variable when importing
`var mongoDb = require('./connect')`

Comment: Yep, no luck with that.